# Create an ARRAY, JQUERY for an SQL DB

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I've got some issues with my multiple form, If I insert a single line and then click "send" the data are properly saved in my SQL database but if I click the "+" button and I create a new line in my form I have just the first entry saved. I guess I have to create an array but I don't know how to do it. The data table is quite simple. This is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Simple PHP contact form with MySQL and Form Validation </title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>


</head>
<body>

<br><br><br>

<div class="container">

    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="thankyou.php" method="post"  id="contact_form">

<fieldset>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Dynamic Form Fields - Add & Remove Multiple fields</div>
  <div class="panel-body">

  <div id="education_fields">

        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="articolazione" name="articolazione[]" value="" placeholder="articolazione">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome[]" value="" placeholder="nome">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cognome" name="cognome[]" value="" placeholder="cognome">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero[]" value="" placeholder="numero">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="citta" name="citta[]" value="" placeholder="citta">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="anno" name="anno[]">
            <option value="">Anno</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            </select>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="education_fields();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

  </div>


</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-12 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Submit" >Invia <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>

  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</form>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>

var room = 1;
function education_fields() {

    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="articolazione" name="articolazione" value="" placeholder="articolazione"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" value="" placeholder="nome"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cognome" name="cognome" value="" placeholder="cognome"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero" value="" placeholder="numero"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="citta" name="citta" value="" placeholder="citta"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" id="anno" name="anno"><option value="">Anno</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option></select><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';

    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
   function remove_education_fields(rid) {
       $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
   }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$articolazione    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['articolazione[]']);
$nome   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nome[]']);
$cognome    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['cognome[]']);
$numero = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['numero[]']);
$citta = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['citta[]']);
$anno = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['anno[]']);





$query   = "INSERT into tb_cform (articolazione,nome,cognome,numero,citta,anno) VALUES('" . $articolazione . "','" . $nome . "','" . $cognome . "','" . $numero . "','" . $citta . "','" . $anno . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Richiesta Inviata con Successo<br>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

and this is the table:

articolazione, nome, cognome, numero, citta, anno

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$articolazione    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['articolazione']);
$nome   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
$cognome    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['cognome']);
$numero = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['numero']);
$citta = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['citta']);
$anno = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['anno']);


$arr = array();
array_push($arr, "articolazione", "nome", "cognome", "numero", "citta", "anno");





$query   = "INSERT into tb_cform (articolazione,nome,cognome,numero,citta,anno) VALUES('" . $articolazione . "','" . $nome. "','" . $cognome . "','" . $numero . "','" . $citta . "','" . $anno . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Richiesta Inviata con Successo<br>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to insert multiple rows in the same action, but I think that my PHP code is incorrect because the first part just send data to the DB the second part doesn't work, I guess I should use a FOR cicle.